# Transform String into Date using DateFormat

Tags: java, date-format

I get this date as a string  from SOAP message

```
"2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00"
```

Most i could i could identify and vary on subject was

to play with this format `yyyy-MM-dd ? hh:mm:ss.????`

I tried different combinations using SSS T z Z instead of '?"

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("... various formats ...");
System.out.println(df.parse("2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00"));
```

but no success.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to change the timezone part. try this:

```
String a = "2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00";
    a = a.replaceFirst(":(?=\\d+$)", "");
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    System.out.println(df.parse(a));
```

Comment: @Cris it simply removes the last colon

Comment: you had eagle eyes to discover the last ":" :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using the standard Java date formatting.
Using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) this can be done using the following code:

```
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder b = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendYear(4, 4).appendLiteral('-').appendMonthOfYear(2).appendLiteral('-').appendDayOfMonth(2)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendHourOfDay(2).appendLiteral(':').appendMinuteOfHour(2).appendLiteral(':').appendSecondOfMinute(2)
            .appendLiteral('.').appendMillisOfSecond(3).appendTimeZoneOffset(null, true, 2, 2);
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeParser = b.toFormatter();
    System.out.println(dateTimeParser.parseDateTime("2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00"));
```

Comment: tried in simple main ....Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00"

Comment: updated answer to point to joda time as your format is not (easily) parseable using the standard Java api.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following.

```
String date = "2009-12-02T12:58:38.415+01:00";
        int lastIndexOf = date.lastIndexOf(":");
        if(lastIndexOf>=0){
        date = date.substring(0,lastIndexOf)+date.substring(lastIndexOf+1);
        }
        System.out.println("~~~~~~date~~~~~"+date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSZ");
        try {
            sdf.parse(date);
            System.out.println("....date..."+date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```